# Mutiple menu icons generated onResume of fragments

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

hey guys this a function in my fragment view to dynamically add a item in my action bar.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         fav = menu.add(1,1,1,"add");
         fav.setIcon(R.drawable.add_label);
         fav.setShowAsAction(2);
    }
```

my problem is when the device is locked and resumed the item duplicates it self in the action bar. any insight to solve the problem is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

```
fav = menu.findItem(R.id.fav);
if(fav == null) {
    fav = menu.add(1,1,1,"add");
}
```

where `R.id.fav` is the id of your item in menu xml layout.

Comment: but the item is generated dynamically.

Comment: Then you can ignore the first line, but the rest is still applicable.